# Chef: Setting environment variables up

Tags: chef-infra

I'm deploying j2ee applications which need environment variables in order to set the application context up. I mean applications are looking for environment variables in order to get the `ACCESS_TOKEN` for getting access to any remote service.

Unfortunately Unix has no general purpose solution for global environment variables. I've took a look over there but I don't quite figure out how to set them up on provisioning. There's a problem with setting variables on bash processes and their inheritance.

According to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117470/181362), I guess there're a lot of things to do in order to work it around.

How could I automate it using chef? My main goal is to set environment variables in order for `wildfly` user to be able to get the `FOO` environment variable value.

I don't know if I've explained so well...

Comment: Usually you set ENV variables in a shell script launching the j2ee app, something like a `setenv.sh` in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Chef because you can't do it at all. If it's a service, put it in the service definition (usually a systemd unit these days). If it's for a user tool, put it in their shell init files. You would do both with a `template` resource, or maybe `poise_service` for the former if feeling very fancy.

Comment: I've tried to get how to get it. Is there any example over there?

Comment: You would have to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to do.